# What happens when I wipe the internal storage of a device using TWRP?

Tags: internal-storage, device-firmware, twrp

When I wipe the internal storage using TWRP recovery, does this fully wipe the contents of the phone's hard disk, leaving a blank, unformatted space? After doing this, will I be able to restore the stock firmware? I have two devices: a Nexus 7 2013 WiFi (flo) and a Moto G 2014 XT1068 (titan).

Comment: Note that phones use Nand(flash) Storage and not HDD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for your first question: no, wiping data from the recovery just wipes the content of the partitions, not the partitions themselves. So your device's disk will still be divided into /data, /system, /cache etc., but those partitions will be blank.

As for your second question, yes, you will be able to restore the stock firmware, as long as you make a backup in the recovery onto an external SD card.

Comment: You also need to differentiate of *what* you wipe. If you only wipe `/data` and `/cache`, you didn't even touch the system, so your device will boot up fine without any additional actions – as basically you've only performed a factory-reset :) If you, however, wipe `/system`, the device will no longer "boot up normally" (but still be able to boot into recovery), and you will have to flash a stock or custom ROM (either from recovery, or via `fastboot`).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was asking about wiping the `Internal Storage` of the device under `Advanced Wipe` in TWRP. I understand about the various partitions but wasn't sure if wiping the internal storage would blank these partitions or remove them from the disk entirely, leaving them to be created and formatted again. Arielle's answer helped my understanding.