# Help while installing stock rom.zip

Tags: stock-rom

While installing the stock rom the steps include

- Open TWRP
- Clean Cache system data
- Install stock rom

When I clean the system data the stock rom zip that I have kept in the sd card also gets deleted. How am I supposed to install the rom ?
I am using TWRP , on a moto G2(2014), an the stock rom is android nougat 7.1

Comment: Just perform 'Factory Reset' in TWRP (Don't wipe `/data` partition).. That way, the files in Internal Storage remains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the ROM zip file in `/data/media` , that won't get wiped, when you wipe with TWRP

That's assuming you don't have an external SD.

See this for more -[What's the difference between Data and Internal Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/161047/131553)

Comment: But how to copy from sd card to  /data/media

Comment: If you're referring to `/sdcard`, which is also known as the `Internal Storage`, then you don't need to copy the file to `/data/media` if it's already in `/sdcard`, as `/data/media` serves as the emulated storage available through `/sdcard` as internal SD card.  But, if you're referring to the external SD card, which is usually located in `/external_sd`, then it's up to you if you want to copy the file to `/data/media`, as you can select which partitions will TWRP wipe.  If you want to copy the file, TWRP has a built-in file manager accessible through `Advanced > File Manager`.